# Unable to import pyperclip in my python IDLE, but able to import from command prompt

Tags: python, python-idle, pyperclip

This is my first question on stackoverflow and I'm new to Python.

I want to import pyperclip module. 
So I went to cmd, ran as administrator, moved to the path using - cd \Program Files\Python37\Scripts and downloaded pip via pip3 install pyperclip command and it is successfully downloaded.

Now from IDLE I'm not able to import it

Following is the output from IDLE, it has not got that pyperclip module to import

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pyperclip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
>>>
```

After this I did some research I found that, there could be possibility that it must have installed in some other directory. so from the research I found pyperclip folder and pyperclip-1.8.0-py3.6.egg-info folder in one of sub directory, which I copied and pasted in C:\Program Files\Python36 directory.

With above thing also I unable to import pyperclip from IDLE.

I went to command prompt, typed python and able to import it

Following is output
C:\Users\Administrator>python

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyperclip
>>>
```

So I'm not able to import from IDLE, but able to do in command prompt.

1 more problem I found as I'm new to python,
IDLE is showing python 3.8.2 and on command prompt it is showing 3.6.  I have downloaded only 1 python and I have only 1 python installed. why there is this version difference 3.6 and 3.8.2

UPDATE:
With following command on IDLE, I able to import pyperclip. But it is only for current opened IDLE. After closing IDLE and reopening it, I have do these commands again. How to fix it for all time

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(1, 'C:/Program Files/Python36')
>>> import pyperclip
~~~~~~~~~~

SOLVED:
```

Comment: It looks like IDLE using one Python interpreter (Python 3.8.2), while in the command-line you run another one (Python 3.6.0), with pyperclip installed. You'd be better off using multiple virtual environments to solve this problem easily, or you may also use single Python interpreter on your machine.

Comment: NEVER do like you've done! You are using the same Python interpreter (3.8.2), though while changing sys.path you are allowing it to use Python 3.6.0 modules, too! It's a very unsafe and bad practice! Look at my previous answer to understand how to solve the problem the right way.

Comment: Instead of writing a solution into your question text, it is better to answer your question. Yes, you can do it, even if it is your own question. Then you can mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @colidyre

Comment: @Demian Wolf I understood your point. Could you just brief about how to do it

Comment: See my answer and this link for more information: https://realpython.com/lessons/creating-virtual-environment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, IDLE is using one Python interpreter (Python 3.8.2), while in the command-line you run another one (Python 3.6.0), with pyperclip installed. You'd be better off to do ONE of the following steps:

1) use multiple virtual environments to solve this problem easily (recommended). Read [this](https://realpython.com/lessons/creating-virtual-environment/) article for more information.

2) install the required module on both Python interpreters, by running `pip install pyperclip` either (depending on the Python version) from `C:\PythonXX\Scripts` or `C:\Program files\PythonXX\Scripts`

3) you may also use single Python interpreter on your machine: remove one of the interpreters and then "Repair" another one (to fix the filetypes associations). To do this, open the installer from Windows uninstall manager and follow the steps it will give you.

Answer (score 0):

I found 1 more python IDLE installed in directory
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
I copied pyperclip folder and pyperclip-1.8.0-py3.6.egg-info folder from C:\Program Files\Python36. And it solved my problem thank you guys

Comment: It is strongly unrecommended to copy packages from one Python interpreter to another as you do! You need simply to install pyperclip with pip again for this Python interpreter. Just goto (with cd command) to C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts and call `pip3.6 install pyperclip` from there.

Comment: PS: I added information about virtualenv usage as a comment under your question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but realized this later...what I figured out was that pip was installing the module into the site-packages folder in the AppData\Roaming location instead of the AppData\Local folder. Once I moved the module's folders into the right spot it worked!

If you also run into this issue, maybe just do a quick check that pip is installing where you want it to. Now to figure out how to change the default install path...